# watch cannot see the changed variable from a service

Tags: angularjs

I have the following piece of code

```
angular.module('plunker', []);

angular.module('plunker').service('MyService', function () {
  this.myVar = null;

  this.setX = function() {
    this.myVar = 'x';
   };
});

angular.module('plunker').controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout, MyService){

  $scope.myService = MyService;

 $scope.$watch('myService.myVar', function(newval, oldval) {
   console.log(newval, oldval);
 });

  $scope.setX = MyService.setX;

 $timeout(function() {
   $scope.setX()
 }, 1000);


});
```

Please note the assignment `$scope.setX = MyService.setX;`.

When it logs in console, it prints only `null null`.
The expected result should be

```
null null
x null
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `$scope.setX()` doesn't change `myVar` from the service.

Comment: Why isn't it changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function at service is overlapping the this variable.
Try to store the "this" variable:

```
angular.module('plunker').service('MyService', function () {
    var self = this;

    self.myVar = null;

    self.setX = function() {
        self.myVar = 'x';
    };
});
```

And optionally, try to use the function watch format:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return  $scope.myService.myVar; },
    function(newval, oldval) {
        console.log(newval, oldval);
    }
);
```

Comment: I cannot change the variable in my watch.

Comment: try this solution. Probably your this variable is obscured by the inner function.

Comment: Your solution worked but I don't understand your explanation. Can you elaborate it please? Thanks!

Comment: I will explain: Each function is an object, and the term "this" is an access to that object. At context "service(...function() { this.myVar = null }" the reference is to the first function... but, at the "...setX = function()..." the this, now, refers to the second just declared function, and not will be exposed for the service... then, when I store the first call in a variable "var self = this", I will use always the same object reference (the service object)